# How do I make a string variable (in c#) bold when converting to html?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, bold

I have this code in C#/ASP.net

```
foreach (String projectType in ProjectsByProjectType.Keys)
{
    HtmlTableRow trh = new HtmlTableRow();
    HtmlTableCell tdProjectType = new HtmlTableCell();
    tdProjectType.InnerHtml = projectType;
    trh.Controls.Add(tdProjectType);
    tableLocal.Controls.Add(trh);
}
```

When this line runs

```
tdProjectType.InnerHtml = projectType;
```

I'd like the text within the `innerHTML` to be in a bold font type (so take the string referenced by 'projectType' and make it bold). How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
foreach (String projectType in ProjectsByProjectType.Keys)
{
    HtmlTableRow trh = new HtmlTableRow();
    HtmlTableCell tdProjectType = new HtmlTableCell();
    tdProjectType.InnerHtml = "<b>"+projectType+"</b>";
    trh.Controls.Add(tdProjectType);
    tableLocal.Controls.Add(trh);
}
```

Comment: This works. But I ended up using 

tdProjectType.Attributes.Add("style", "font-weight:bold");

instead

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`<b>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b) tag:

```
 tdProjectType.InnerHtml = "<b>" + projectType + "</b>";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the semantically correct way would be to use one of the following in preferential order

`tdProjectType.InnerHtml = "<h2>" + projectType "</h2>";`

or whichever h tag you want to use

`tdProjectType.InnerHtml = "<strong>" + projectType "</strong>";`
 `tdProjectType.InnerHtml = "<b>" + projectType "</b>";`

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple you just need to write the string in bold tags like:

```
<b> String</b>
```